# Article alias not show in browser url in Joomla 3.0

Tags: url, alias, joomla3.0, article

My doubt is about the urls:

In Joomla 3.0 I proceed steps for SEO, rename the `.htaccess` etc.
But example if I create one article with alias: article-url-teste.

I go the menu create one sub-menu item with the same alias for single article.

When I click in submenu item in fontend the article show me ok but the url site/article-url-teste not show, show me the alias the root menu.

I like show alias of the articles.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the menu items setup.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla SEF urls are not magic bullets in that once enabled you can access any article using the alias.  What you described is the correct behavior for how you configured the menu.  If you want to be able to access the article directly using the alias you need to create a dedicated menu item.

I usually created a dedicated menutype called Placement or Hidden with articles and any other endpoint I need to be SEF alias accessible.  The only major difference being you don't attach the menutype to a mod_menus module for display.